# ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to move the services to AWS ECS using ecs-cli but they fail with error

`ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty`

docker-compose file is in https://github.com/eventuate-examples/eventuate-examples-restaurant-management.git

`ecs-cli compose up
WARN[0000] The DOCKER_HOST_IP variable is not set. Substituting a blank string.
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=zookeeper
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=cdcservice
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=kafka
WARN[0000] Environment variable is unresolved. Setting it to a blank value...  key name=ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=mysql
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=redis
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=build service name=restaurants
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=restaurants
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=build service name=restaurantsview
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=restaurantsview
ERRO[0000] Error registering task definition             error="ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 5fac2301-e8a3-11e8-bbf8-d73777446b76" family=opt
ERRO[0000] Create task definition failed                 error="ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 5fac2301-e8a3-11e8-bbf8-d73777446b76"
FATA[0000] ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty.
        status code: 400, request id: 5fac2301-e8a3-11e8-bbf8-d73777446b76`

Comment: It seems that there is some issue with the image variable. Can you post your yaml configuration file?

Comment: yaml file available at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KjcIP2H-h7tkDOdqcCK6Q21zpxdTEfkm